# Adding new record to a VFP data table in VB.NET with ADO recordsets

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, visual-foxpro

I am trying to add a new record to a Visual FoxPro data table using an ADO dataset with no luck.  The code runs fine with no exceptions  but when I check the dbf after the fact there is no new record.  The mDataPath variable shown in the code snippet is the path to the .dbc file for the entire database.  A note about the For loop at the bottom; I am adding the body of incoming emails to this MEMO field so thought I needed to break the addition of this string into 256 character Chunks.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
cnn1.Open("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};" & _
                "SourceType=DBC;" & _
                "SourceDB=" & mDataPath & ";Exclusive=No")

Dim RS As ADODB.RecordsetS = New ADODB.Recordset       
RS.Open("select * from gennote", cnn1, 1, 3, 1)
RS.AddNew()

'Assign values to the first three fields
RS.Fields("ignnoteid").Value = NextIDI 
RS.Fields("cnotetitle").Value = "'" & mail.Subject & "'"
RS.Fields("cfilename").Value = "''"

'Looping through 254 characters at a time and add the data
'to Ado Field buffer
For i As Integer = 1 To Len(memo) Step liChunkSize
            liStartAt = i
            liWorkString = Mid(mail.Body, liStartAt, liChunkSize)
            RS.Fields("mnote").AppendChunk(liWorkString)            
 Next

'Update the recordset
RS.Update()
RS.Requery()
RS.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208208) that matches your question exactly.  The only major difference between your code and the example provided is the **BackgroundFetch** setting in the connection string.  This setting is enabled, by default, and has been [reported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269881) to cause numerous problems with cursors.

In addition, you might want to switch to the [Visual Foxpro Ole Db driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70acczs0%28VS.80%29.aspx).  The [Visual Foxpro ODBC driver](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271908) was retired around 2000.